# when i add margin to my row of fluid container my one div shifts down how to prevent that?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI5hu.jpg)

```
<div class=" fluid-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div  class="col-lg-3">
    yo
          </div>
          <div   class="col-lg-3">
    bo
          </div>
          <div   class="col-lg-3">
    so
          </div>
          <div  id="a" class="col-lg-3">
    ko
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

//////////////////////CSS/////////////////////////////////

```
    .col-lg-3{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 1px;
  }
```

even if i add margin as small as 1px my last div shifts in one row down how to prevent that? help i am stuck for many hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you're using 4 col-lg-3 which 3*4=12 which takes the whole row and when you even add 1px margin it gets bigger than the scope of the row and it goes to the next row.
I don't know what you are trying to do but maybe you can use col-lg-2